# Finding the output of the nested CompoundExpression

Tags: expression-manipulation, scoping

I am trying to catch the output expression of a nested `CompoundExpression` like this

```mathematica
Hold[
 Module[{y},
   y = x^2;
   ListLinePlot[Table[Sin[y i] // N, {i, 0, 100}]]
 ]
];
cases = % // Cases[#, CompoundExpression[rest__, last_] :> Hold[last], All] &
cases // Last
```

Expected result is `Hold[ListLinePlot[...]]` at the last position of a list or at `-1`. However, for some reason the desired result is located at

```
In: cases[[-4]]
Out: Hold[ListLinePlot[Table[N[Sin[y i]], {i, 0, 100}]]]
```

Is there a reliable way to capture the output expression of the nested functions without evaluating it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your current pattern also matches every *single* expression. You should make a pattern that matches only those `CompoundExpression`s which have at least two expressions (and are therefore "true" compound expressions). One way to do this:

```
expr = Hold[Module[{y}, y = x^2;
    ListLinePlot[Table[Sin[y i] // N, {i, 0, 100}]]]];

Cases[expr, 
 HoldPattern[CompoundExpression[expr1_, expr2__]] :> 
  Hold[expr1; expr2], All]

(* {Hold[y = x^2; ListLinePlot[Table[N[Sin[y i]], {i, 0, 100}]]]} *)
```

Comment: Thanks @Domen! I would also change this to `CompoundExpression[expr1__, expr2_]`, that the last one will be captured.